# Changing the Global GA Object in google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The Google Analytics tracking code is clashing with the tracking code for another program and I have been advised to change the name of the Global GA Object from “ga” to something else like ‘_gaTracker

I have found the Google page on how to change this code but we utilise the Universal Analytics tag in Google Tag Manager and I can't find any documentation about ho to change the name of the Global GA Object there.

Answer (score 1):

UA Tag -> More Settings -> Advanced Configuration -> Global Function Name.

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to use Variable to deliver custom object name into Google Analytics Tag.